# How to maintain a global variable's value after it has been manipulated by a while loop?

Tags: arduino

So recently I have been working on a project which involves the use of while loops to manipulate global variables. My hope is to use the while loop as a sort of counter. However, I am finding that when the while loop has terminated, the value of the global variable reverts to zero. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
int i = 0;

setup() {

    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

}

loop() {

    while (i < 10) {
        i++;
    }

    analogWrite(3, i);

}
```

After the while loop has terminated, I find that no signal is written to pin 3, and i has been reset to zero. is there any way for it to retain its value?

I understand that the example given is very simple, and the project I am currently working on is much more complicated, but I am just wondering if it is even possible for a variable to retain its value after being incremented in a while loop.

Comment: No, with that code i will be forever at 10 after the loop runs once, pin 3 will have analogWrite 10 on it and after the first iteration of loop the while loop will never run again.  Perhaps you made some mistake in some other code and it seemed to be reset.  From this code you'd never know because you don't output anything to tell you the value of i.

Comment: Post the actual code that caused the actual problem.  Or at least one that you tested and can show the output from.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed you code so it would compile (another clue you didn't actually test THAT code) and added some debug prints to prove that i stays at 10.

```
int i = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("Loop start i = ");
  Serial.println(i);

  while (i < 10) {
    Serial.println("Running while loop");
    i++;
  }

  analogWrite(3, i);

  Serial.print("Loop end i = ");
  Serial.println(i);

}
```

Produces as output:

```
Loop start i = 0
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Running while loop
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
Loop start i = 10
Loop end i = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to `write` outside of your while loop... all that's doing is incrementing i to 10 exiting the loop, then writing to pint 3...

also... re global... no unless you write i to another variable at the start of your function "loop"  ie z ... int z = i; then at the end of the function i = z;

globals are bad mmmkkkaaay!! pass variables as parameters.